# Compute TxID of Bitcoin Transaction

Tags: transactions, hash, transaction-id

*Originally posted to StackOverflow but with no response. Thought I might have better luck here.*

I've successfully created a Bitcoin transaction in C# according to the protocol specifications. Here's the transaction in binary:

`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`

I know the transaction is solid because the BTCs were transmitted properly. Furthermore, pasting my transaction above into [this validator](https://blockchain.info/decode-tx) indicates the correct values.

What's stumping me is how the official transaction ID is generated. Everything on the Bitcoin and StackOverflow StackExchange sites indicate that it's generated by hashing the transaction bytes twice. I tried to do so as follows:

```
const String txHex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

SHA256Managed sha256Hasher=new SHA256Managed();
Func<byte[],byte[]> doubleHash=(bytes)=>{
    return sha256Hasher.ComputeHash((sha256Hasher.ComputeHash(bytes)));
};
String txidHex=Utils.ToHex(doubleHash(Utils.FromHex(txHex)));
```

`Utils.ToHex()` and `Utils.FromHex()` are helper functions copied from StackOverflow which convert between `byte[]` and a hex string.

The code above yields a `txidHex` value of `27E6C3EF18D14FB49CBAC182BBDB47FC9D6F79DA65C101873207B60A957852A7` but searching [BlockExplorer.com](http://BlockExplorer.com) for that particular txid yields no results.

I mentioned earlier that my transaction *did* execute properly. It turns out that it did so using a txid of `11172aed3a61fe64ae82cb02e886757d352a4452f956a0703d0809880538ba58`. If you paste that txid into BlockExplorer you'll see my transaction.

Which leads me to my question: Given a valid transaction byte stream (byte[]), how does one correctly compute a transaction ID?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. You've forgotten to convert from internal byte order (used in transactions to specify outpoints,) to output byte order (displayed to users.) Reverse the bytes after the second hash.

   See also: [How do I calculate the txid of this raw transaction?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32765/how-do-i-calculate-the-txid-of-this-raw-transaction)
2. The transaction you've included in your question and the transaction on the blockchain are slightly different. However, since they reference the same outpoint, they cannot coexist in the blockchain.

   Blockchain:

   ```
   TXID: 11172aed3a61fe64ae82cb02e886757d352a4452f956a0703d0809880538ba58

   010000000162ef5d87e91090453009860c6f135ea2a490133b2633f8f7ba014889f5ff7e4a00000000
   8b48304502205abb829faec8571a6469d40edbceb7938dbb5eeb0efa5b6b284d9730eb8e90a7022100
   c0aec347ffa72ed22057a821b0219e114a3d2686eb67904403529eac4e2c7c260141040bcf1becf4ef
   6a5c24fd790ca86e8dcdfa3538cb97e99c254f84d209cfe47bfc6bf3b11aca05db7c7638301711070f
   176e848b650a406eb7afc30aa9ea242489ffffffff02404b4c00000000001976a9140a24f0387f05a6
   eecd1f8b327bb442eab767cbc888acca165e00000000001976a914f8fb3b4e5d75652795dd13b209e0
   be7bbd66b5d488ac00000000
   ```

   Question:

   ```
   TXID: a75278950ab607328701c165da796f9dfc47dbbb82c1ba9cb44fd118efc3e627

   010000000162ef5d87e91090453009860c6f135ea2a490133b2633f8f7ba014889f5ff7e4a00000000
   8a4730440220497e2d3f9bbbc0c122d839968ff880514440ced08a71d28e614ff4c871964024022049
   687008e4af72682992325f17e95da382d63e3fb14605a81b4498dff9210e310141040bcf1becf4ef6a
   5c24fd790ca86e8dcdfa3538cb97e99c254f84d209cfe47bfc6bf3b11aca05db7c7638301711070f17
   6e848b650a406eb7afc30aa9ea242489ffffffff02404b4c00000000001976a9140a24f0387f05a6ee
   cd1f8b327bb442eab767cbc888acca165e00000000001976a914f8fb3b4e5d75652795dd13b209e0be
   7bbd66b5d488ac00000000
   ```

Comment: Thanks, man.. This bitcoin protocol is some fascinating stuff! I'm going to dig into the info you've provided.

Comment: It's just weird mostly, the endianness of elements in transactions flips for no discernible reason. There's no standard for it in Bitcoin whatsoever. Just be aware that hashes for blocks and transactions are internally little endian but are displayed big endian to users.

Comment: Wow, ok, I think I get it now. Everything you stated makes sense but it leads me to a different question: Why is the transaction that was finalized in the block chain slightly different from what I submitted in my original question? The inputs/outputs are all correct. Everything looks good. Yet the transaction bytes are slightly different.

Comment: B/c your Tx has a different signature `48304502205abb829faec8571a6469d40edbceb7938dbb5eeb0efa5b6b284d9730eb8e90a7022100c0aec347ffa72ed22057a821b0219e114a3d2686eb67904403529eac4e2c7c260141040bcf1becf4ef6a5c24fd790ca86e8dcdfa3538cb97e99c254f84d209cfe47bfc6bf3b11aca05db7c7638301711070f176e848b650a406eb7afc30aa9ea242489` Vs `4730440220497e2d3f9bbbc0c122d839968ff880514440ced08a71d28e614ff4c871964024022049687008e4af72682992325f17e95da382d63e3fb14605a81b4498dff9210e310141040bcf1becf4ef6a5c24fd790ca86e8dcdfa3538cb97e99c254f84d209cfe47bfc6bf3b11aca05db7c7638301711070f176e848b650a406eb7afc30aa9ea242489`